# Understanding 気分任せの足跡

Tags: translation, particle-の, phrases, song-lyrics

I'm translating the song “はだしの軌跡” from **Final Fantasy X-2: Vocal Collection - Rikku**.

> 気分まかせの足跡つけて新しい地図 描こう

I’m translating this lyric from right to left, reading as “Let’s draw a new map by...” 気分まかせの足跡つけて seems to mean something about making footprints of some kind. まかせ appears to either be the stem form of 任せる or act like a suffix to 気分, but I don't know what the ‘no’ particle is for if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here まかせ seems to act as the suffix meaning "leave it up to someone or something else". In this case it's being applied to 気分 (the feeling / mood). Giving 気分まかせ a meaning of "left up to the feeling / mood".

As for the の particle, it's being used in the traditional sense to connect and modify 足跡 (footprints) using 気分まかせ. So with this の particle we get 気分まかせの足跡 meaning something like "the feeling / mood's footprints", "the footprints based on the mood", or etc.

Also for extra clarification, 足跡つけて (足跡をつける) means to "leave behind / make footprints".

So altogether reading from left to right we have something like:

> 気分まかせの足跡つけて新しい地図描こう
>
> Leaving behind footprints based on the mood, let's draw a new map

Or reading from right to left

> Let's draw a new map using the footprints left behind by the mood.

Comment: 足跡つけて does not mean "follow the footprints".

Comment: So 気分まかせの足跡つけて新しい地図描こう means something like “Let's draw a new map by letting the mood guide our footprints“?

Comment: @naruto 足跡つけて must mean “footprints left (as markings)” then. So overall, something like “Let’s draw a new map using the footprints left behind by the mood”

Comment: @Tylersanzura It's 足跡**を**つけて, so a literal translation would be "Making/Leaving freewheeling footprints, let's draw a new map".

Comment: @naruto Yep, the を particle is omitted here and I can agree with that translation